# Not Recieving data into text file on sending Machine Credentials in TCP/IP protocol

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener, tcp

I have a PBX machine which i need to communicate using Ip and Port number along with the username and password.At present i am able to connect to the machine by using the ip address and port number.But On sending the Username and password to the machine for authentication i am not getting the required data out from the machine into the text file instead i am getting the username and password send to the machine in format like this into the text file.

Here is my code in c#..

```
        ipaddress = "";
        int port = int.Parse("");
        textfileSaveLocation = "";

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string stringData;
        //string input;

            IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Parse(ipaddress);
            IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(ipadd,port);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sock.NoDelay = false;
            try
            {
                sock.Connect(ipend);
                textBox4.AppendText("Connected to host" + "\r\n");
            }
            catch (Exception dfg)
            {
                textBox4.AppendText("Problem connecting to host" + "\r\n");
                textBox4.AppendText(dfg.ToString ()+"\r\n");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                int recv = sock.Receive(data);
                stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                textBox4.AppendText(stringData + "\r\n");
                while (true)
                {
                    Byte[] bBuf;
                    string buf;


                    Application.DoEvents();

                    buf = String.Format("{0}/{1}", "SMDR", "PCCSMDR");
                    bBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buf);
                    sock.Send(bBuf);     


                    data = new byte[1024];
                    recv = sock.Receive(data);
                    stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                    textBox4.AppendText(stringData + "\r\n");
                    string df = "";
                     try

        }
```

I am trying to figure out the mistake from two days but not able to find out..Just help me out where i am going wrong..

Comment: Although I have no idea what protocol you are using to communicate, the message you send probably needs some termination character, like `"SMDR/PCCSMDR\n"` so the server knows you're done sending the message. Any protocol over TCP requires either a length prefix or termination suffix to a message.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I am using TCP/IP protocol and communicating to the machine using Ethernet(LAN) wire.Here is the link for my machine.Here is the link where username and password is suggested http://www.aggsoft.com/pbx/panasonic-kx-tda600.htm

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I am using Ethernet/IP protocol to send message to the machine

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification](http://aggsoft.com/pbx/panasonic-kx-tda600.htm) mentions:

> You can activate the "ASCII Data Query" plugin and specify the login/password request as:
>   SMDR#0D#0APCCSMDR#0D#0A

So both the username and password will need to be carriage return-terminated:

```
buf = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n", "SMDR", "PCCSMDR");
```

Comment: if i pass suggested with.                                          bBuf=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buf);
                    sock.Send(bBuf); then can the connection will happen successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much sir..what does this mean in the given specification line..SMDR#0D#0APCCSMDR#0D#0A .Please help me as i am struck into the situation.

Comment: `#0D` means the character represented by hexadecimal value `0D`, or decimal 13, and `#0A` is decimal 10. These two characters commonly set the cursor to the leftmost position on a new line. Your PBX demands that you terminate the username and password with these characters. In C# they can be entered as `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Thank you sir for our kind response .buf = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n", "SMDR", "PCCSMDR");  Adding this line would connect my application to Pbx ..Am i right sir?

Comment: @Adi I have never worked with that PBX, but as far as I can tell that's the correct way to create a login message.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special format string that the specified software uses to send login and passowrd.

The command string will be interpreted as:

SMDR<CR><LF>PCCSMDR<CR><LF>

Comment: can i send the login password in this formate buf = String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n", "SMDR", "PCCSMDR");

Comment: what does this line SMDR#0D#0APCCSMDR#0D#0A means with respect to SMDR<CR><LF>PCCSMDR<CR><LF>

Comment: Yes, you can send String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n", "SMDR", "PCCSMDR"). <CR><LF> mean these ASCII characters. They are specified in the format string as \r and \n.